# Installing a Library on Centos Server

Tags: centos, installation, library

We have one NIS server in our lab and want to install Blas library on it.
We have one Master computer, one file server computer, and 13 clusters and all are using Centos. My question is how can we do it and where should we install it? on File Server, or Master, or all clusters?
Thanks.